Django tinymce makes all text fields a rich text editor
I am using a DRF as my backend. I configured django parler to manage my translations.
I would like to use TinyMCE and normal text fields on the same admin page.
This is my model:
from django.db import models
from parler.models import TranslatedFields, TranslatableModel, TranslatedField
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

from core.utils import validate_image_size


class SportCard(TranslatableModel):
    sport = models.ForeignKey('Sport', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Sport út')
    name = TranslatedField(any_language=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', validators=[validate_image_size])
    description = TranslatedField(any_language=True)
    summary = TranslatedField(any_language=True)

    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name=models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=255),
        description=HTMLField(_("description")),
        summary=models.TextField(_("summary")),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

However on the admin page the models.TextField shows as a TinyMCE:

This is the config in my settings.py:

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'height': 360,
    'width': 800,
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'silver',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
    'convert_urls': False,
    'font_family_formats': '''
            Josefin Sans=Josefin Sans,sans-serif;
            Open Sans=Open Sans,sans-serif;
            Playfair Display=Playfair Display,serif;
            ''',
}

